# How to change the dynamic resources in the button click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF i need to learn the static resources and dynamic resources, i have tried to set the Style for Button using Dynamic Resource and change the style using button click but style is not changed, please refer my below code i used for change the button style using click,

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>  
<Button x:Name="Content" Content="Content" Height="30" Width="200" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Style1}" Click="Content_Click" />
```

Click :

```
 private void Content_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   this.Resources.Add("Style1", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
 }
```

Could you please any one guide me how to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Add like this hence you can overwrite the `Style1` with the new `style`:

```
private void Content_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
       Style style = new Style{ TargetType = typeof(Button)};
       style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Blue));
       this.Resources["Style1"] = style;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to the Resource of the code must identify them in the file App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Style1" />
</Application.Resources>
```

The Resource can be changed in code line of the form:

`Application.Current.Resources["MyResource"] = MyNewValue;`

```
private void Content_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    SolidColorBrush MyBrush = Brushes.Blue;

    // Set the value
    Application.Current.Resources["DynamicBG"] = MyBrush;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are learning `DynamicResource`, the **correct way** would be

*Xaml:*

```
<Window.Resources>        
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DynamicBG" Color="Red"/>         
</Window.Resources>    

<Button x:Name="button" Content="Content" Height="30" Width="200" Background="{DynamicResource DynamicBG}" Click="Content_Click"/>
```

*Code Behind:*

```
private void Content_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Resources["DynamicBG"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}
```

*Additional Note:*

You can see that, on **changing the `Button` with `Background="{StaticResource DynamicBG}"`will not change the `Color` on Buttonclick**.  That's where the `Dynamic` key play its role.